# Can I use two monitors each connected to my GPU and motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a Geforce GT 640 and I'm thinking of running dual monitors on my system. I have two VGA monitors, and I'm aware that I have two DVI-D's and an HDMI port on my card, which I would not buy adapters for it. Can I extend my desktop with integrated graphics enabled? And if i'm gaming, would it only display on the monitor where it's connected to my GPU? I don't mind gaming on one screen.

EDIT: My motherboard is a Gigabyte H61M-S2P

Comment: We would need to know what motherboard you have. Most motherboards turn off the onboard video once it detects a video card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes, but be ready for some instability problems.

Many motherboards will automatically disable the internal graphics when one connected to the x16 slot is detected. Most also allow one re-enable the option.

I don't own a GB motherboard so the instructions are a little bit generic.

1. Restart your computer into your BIOS, whether it be CMOS or UEFI.
2. Go to the **Options** tab
3. Use your arrow keys to navigate to the Video selection.
4. Select the graphics option and select **IGD** or **Integrated**
5. Save and Reboot.

I personally use a similar setup, and can verify that it works on Windows 10. Screen mirroring isn't available but usually isn't needed.